# How do I reset revapi / maven to avoid issues given a previous version?

Tags: revapi

I am on say `0.0.21-SNAPSHOT` I just started using RevAPI and when I do it mentions there have been breaking changes. I can silence it like...

```
<versionIncreaseAllows>
    <major>breaking</major>
    <minor>breaking</minor>
    <patch>breaking</patch>
    <!-- TODO: Even though I have leaving in commented code we should really figure out how to make it the following. -->
    <!--                                <minor>nonBreaking</minor>-->
    <!--                                <patch>equivalent</patch>-->
</versionIncreaseAllows>
```

But as you can see I would rather use a more semantic versioning going forward.

Can I tell RevAPI with maven to reset?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the simplest solution is just to disable Revapi before you release your `0.0.21` version and enable it right afterwards. To disable it, the simplest thing is just to skip the execution using the `<skip>true</true>` in the `revapi-maven-plugin` configuration.

If you don't want to do that, you can configure Revapi to use different configuration for each version of your library - e.g. https://revapi.org/revapi-maven-plugin/0.14.3/configuring-revapi.html#_custom_root_element_of_configuration (or you could come up with some setup where the config for each version was contained in a different file for example).

There, for version `0.0.21` (i.e. the to-be-released version) you'd configure Revapi to ignore all differences, e.g.:

```json
{
  "extension": "revapi.differences",
  "configuration": {
    "justification": "This is a baseline version for the future versions. We ignore any API changes made here as compared with older versions.",
    "ignore": true,
    "differences": [
      {
        "regex": true,
        "code": ".*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

see https://revapi.org/revapi-basic-features/differences.html for details on the `revapi.differences` configuration.